# Result of Replaced/Overriden Parameterless Method Not Passed to the Constructor

Tags: groovy, expandometaclass

I'm trying to change the behaviour of the constructor of a groovy class by replacing a method in that class which is used to set a property but the properties are not getting set with the expected values.

```
class TestClass {

    def noParam
    def withParam

    TestClass() {
        noParam = noParam()
        withParam = withParam('second test')
    }

    def noParam() {
        return 'first test'
    }

    def withParam(param) {
        return param
    }

}

TestClass.metaClass.withParam =  { param -> 'pass' }
TestClass.metaClass.noParam = {-> 'pass' }

def test = new TestClass()

assert test.withParam('dummy') == 'pass' //passes
assert test.withParam == 'pass' // fails
assert test.noParam() == 'pass' // passes
assert test.noParam == 'pass' // fails
```

Comment: I think this is related to groovy generating, for `noParam()` a method which receives an `Object` as a parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Groovy is not using your metaclass overrides in the TestClass constructor when it executes the `noParam` and `withParam` methods.  In fact, if you type the parameter in your `withParam` method, the 2nd assert will also fail.

```
class TestClass {

    def noParam
    def withParam

    TestClass() {
        noParam = noParam()
        withParam = withParam('second test')
        println "in the constructor: noParam = $noParam, withParam = $withParam"
    }

    def noParam() {
        return 'first test'
    }

    def withParam(String param) {
        return param
    }
}

TestClass.metaClass.withParam = { String param -> 'pass' }
TestClass.metaClass.noParam = {-> 'pass' }

def test = new TestClass()

assert test.withParam('dummy') == 'pass'
assert test.withParam  == 'pass' // this fails now too!
assert test.noParam() == 'pass'
assert test.noParam == 'pass' // this fails
```

Here's the output: `in the constructor: noParam = first test, withParam = second test`

`test.withParam` and `test.noParam` are actually calling `test.getWithParam()` and `test.getNoParam()` - they are returning the property values set in the constructor.

`test.withParam('dummy')` and `test.noParam()` are calling your metaclass method and returning "pass".

As far as *why* groovy does not use the metaclass method in your constructor, I'm not sure...  I couldn't find anything in the [metaclass documentation](http://groovy.codehaus.org/JN3525-MetaClasses)...

Maybe you could use static methods instead?

```
class TestClass {

    def noParam
    def withParam

    TestClass() {
        noParam = TestClass.noParam()
        withParam = TestClass.withParam('second test')
        println "in the constructor: noParam = $noParam, withParam = $withParam"
    }

    static def noParam() {
        return 'first test'
    }

    static def withParam(String param) {
        return param
    }
}

TestClass.metaClass.'static'.withParam = { String param -> 'pass' }
TestClass.metaClass.'static'.noParam = {-> 'pass' }

def test = new TestClass()

assert test.withParam('dummy') == 'pass'
assert test.withParam  == 'pass' // passes!
assert test.noParam() == 'pass'
assert test.noParam == 'pass' // passes!
```

Here's the output: `in the constructor: noParam = pass, withParam = pass`